# what is the meaning behind putting a semicolon before a Boolean expression in this code?

Tags: javascript

In the below code, A,B and C are nodes and the interconnections between the nodes given in the connections array. What is the use of the semicolon in the for loop.

```
const connections = ["A-B","B-C"]
let reachable = Object.create(null)
for (let [from, to] of connections.map(conn => conn.split("-"))) {
    ;(reachable[from] || (reachable[from] = [])).push(to)
    ;(reachable[to] || (reachable[to] = [])).push(from)
  }
```

The output reachable is:

```
{ A: [ 'B' ], B: [ 'A', 'C' ], C: [ 'B' ] }
```

Comment: Just a coding style. Effect is the same as if they were at the end of the previous lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is necessary because the JavaScript interpreter wouldn’t know to separate the two lines of code without a special character to denote that (aka `;`). `()`, as I’m sure you know, is used to invoke function calls, and so any time it shows up, the interpreter will try to invoke a function based on the preceding characters, unless they form a keyword (like `if` or `while` or something). In line 4 of this code, the semicolon is unnecessary, because the preceding character will be recognized by the interpreter as not a potentially-function-variable (technical jargon, lol). However, in line 5, without the semicolon to separate them (new line is not sufficient), the interpreter will try to invoke `.push(to)(...)` which would obviously end badly.

Read more about this, and get caught up on the technical jargon that I can’t supply here: https://standardjs.com/rules.html#semicolons